# AWS Sagemaker ClientError: Unable to initialize the algorithm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Cannot run hyper-parameter auto tuning jobs using the image classification algorithm.

Getting this from Sagemaker job info:

> Failure reason
>   ClientError: Unable to initialize the algorithm. Failed to validate input data configuration. (caused by ValidationError) Caused by: Additional properties are not allowed (u'val' was unexpected) Failed validating u'additionalProperties' in schema: {u'$schema': u'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#', u'additionalProperties': False, u'anyOf': [{u'required': [u'train']}, {u'required': [u'validation']}, {u'optional': [u'train_lst']}, {u'optional': [u'validation_lst']}, {u'optional': [u'model']}], u'definitions': {u'data_channel': {u'properties': {u'ContentType': {u'type': u'string'}}, u'type': u'object'}}, u'properties': {u'model': {u'$ref': u'#/definitions/data_channel'}, u'train': {u'$ref': u'#/definitions/data_channel'}, u'train_lst': {u'$ref': u'#/definitions/data_channel'}, u'validation': {u'$ref': u'#/definitio

CloudWatch is giving me this reason:

> 00:42:35
>   2018-12-09 22:42:35 Customer Error: Unable to initialize the algorithm. Failed to validate input data configuration. (caused by ValidationError)
>
> Caused by: Additional properties are not allowed (u'val' was
>   unexpected)

Any help please thanks.

Comment: Did the solution below work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as showed in your log, one of input channels was named as `val`. The correct channel name for validation data should be `validation`. More details on input configuration can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/image-classification.html